# How can I safely kill this spid that is running on the master database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping

I have a secondary logshipping database that is blocked by a pending restore. There is no process (spid) on this database itself, but I found a spid related to this database, that runs on the master database.

The spid in sp_who2

```
-   SPID=120
-   Status=SUSPENDED
-   Login=ABC\sqlagentuser
-   HostName=XYZ
-   BlkBy=  .
-   DBName=master
-   Command=RESTORE LOG
-   CPUTime=2153
-   DiskIO=176
-   LastBatch=09/21 00:46:02
-   Program Name= SQL Server Log Shipping                       
-   REQUESTID=0

More info with another query on sysprocesses and sysdatabases

-   Login_time=2019-09-21 00:46:01.857
-   Memusage=3
-   Lastwaittype= REQUEST_DISPENSER_PAUSE
```

What can I do to get safely rid of this proces? You can see that the master database is involved, that is why I hesitate on killing the spid or restarting any services (or rebooting).

- Can I safely kill it? Will there be any long-time hindrance for other databases on the same instance while doing an eventual rollback? It is already suspended for a couple of days, but it is only waiting (no query activity)
- Or is stopping sqlagent the thing to do? (the process is run by the user that runs the sqlagent-service) – will this kill the spid?
- Or do I have to stop and restart the sql server service (“program name” is sql server log shipping) – any longtime rollback risk during stopping (that will block other databases for that long time)?

Comment: Is one of your log shipping jobs in a running state for a long period? Also, the LastBatch column indicates the LastBatch was in 2021.......that is not right. Was someone messing with system date/time? Try stopping your running log shipping jobs then restarting them.

Comment: HandyD, that date was wrong (changed in a prior edit),  i changed it now. I already did what you suggested (first thing), I stopped the logshipping job that was stuck and than rerun it. It broke because the database was already in use. In the meantime logshipping is disabled on the primary.

Comment: I see I did not give any feedback upon what happened next. In spite of having asked not to reboot the server for any update in the meantime... someone did reboot it overnight. I don't know if it took a long time or not, all I remember is all went well and the spid was gone.